# Is there an official way to add Simulacrum to a sorcerer's spell list besides the Wish spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, simulacrum

I know of the [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell being a possible solution. Are there any others? I'm asking for a 13th-level non-multiclassed sorcerer to be able to learn and cast [*simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum), as if it were on the sorcerer spell list.

**Is there an official way to add *simulacrum* to a (non-multiclassed) sorcerer's spell list, besides the *wish* spell?**

Comment: Would you call a Sorcerer 7/Wizard 13 a "Sorcerer"? :v

Comment: Jokes aside, as the dark wanderer noted, why exactly do you want it in the Sorcerer Spell List, specifically? Or do you just want your sorcerer to be able to learn/cast it? Also, do you want a full sorcerer, or as mentioned in the answer, multiclassing 17 levels in other class is okay?

Comment: If you are a Sorcerer 7/Wizard 13 you are a ""sorcerer"" that knows Simulacrum, but it is not in the Sorcerer's spell list - it is on the Wizard's. There are a few other ways to learn/cast spells that are *not* in your spell list.

Comment: There are sources other than a classes spell list that may grant spells.  That said, most of those sources won't grant a spell as high as level as simulacrum.

Comment: Is "at will" correct here in this question?  The phrase "at will" in 5e implies as many times a day as the player wants not bound by the number of available spell slots -- typically when "at will" is used in the PHB it is part of "at will, without expending a spell slot".  Most of those appear as class features like Warlock's Eldritch Invocations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Ask Your DM (Nicely)

The DM is allowed to change some (read: all) of the rules as they see fit. On page 287, there is a subsection titled Changing Spell Lists. By simply asking your DM, they may decide that Rule of Cool wins here, and let you select it. You may wish to suggest removing some other spell from their list, but honestly for Sorcerers, this is pretty lame. You'd have had to ignore some of those level 7 spells anyway unlike, say, Clerics.

#### Make Friends With A Wizard, Then Ask Your DM (Nicely)

Wizards are all about arcane research. Ask your DM what it would take for such a researcher to invent a new spell, *ritual simulacrum*, which behaves exactly as *simulacrum* but has the ritual tag (see DMG 283, Creating a Spell). From there, your sorcerer would need an int or wis of 13 or higher for the Ritual Caster feat. From there, simply copy it into his ritual book.

#### Beg a Blessing From Your DM (Nicely, of course)

Blessings (DMG 227) are supernatural gifts bestowed on a character. Generally, "a typical blessing mimics the properties of a wondrous item". I'm not aware of one that adds spells known like this specifically, but your DM may be willing to consider this an appropriate reward for some task.

Comment: Just being nitpicky but the second part of this answer assumes feats are an option at that DM's table.